# Turn the bike/turn the bike around

Tags: word-usage, american-english

When someone is turning the bike,what will be a natural way to say that ( not left or right but around).

> Do you know how to turn a bike?
>
> Do you know how to turn a bike around?

What sounds natural ?

Comment: How could anyone *not* know how to turn a bike around? Is there more to the specific situation than is given in the sentence?

Comment: I agree with @JasonB – I can't really imagine anyone asking this question, so it's hard to judge if it sounds "natural" or not. In other words, "turn a bike around" sounds just fine, and so does "Do you know how to". But "Do you know how to turn a bike around?" sounds peculiar. Although, say, for an out-and-back race, someone may ask: "Do you know **where** we turn our bikes around?"

Answer (score 1):

To me *turn a bike* suggests picking up a stationary bike, and putting it down facing the other way.

The word I would use for causing a moving bike to change direction is *steer*, not *turn*.

Answer (score 0):

If the bike is going west, and you want it to go east instead, you could ask:

> Do you know how to make a U-turn on a bike?

A U-turn is a 180 degree change in the direction of a vehicle's motion.  Unless the vehicle can "turn on a dime", the path of the vehicle's motion is shaped like a capital letter "U".

If it is clear from the context that you are talking about riding bikes, you can omit "on a bike":

> Do you know how to make a U-turn?